# Find which physical hard drive is represented in path letters

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I recently installed a new hard drive to my Windows computer, I want to format the old one but I'm not sure if it's C or D, how can I find out?

Comment: what have you tried and where are you getting stuck? I.E.: Have you tried looking in the "Disk Management" console yet?

Comment: Yes, the two drives just have generic names.

Comment: Are both drives the same size, or are they different in size? Right-clicking a drive and access its properties may give you an indication to what which drive is. Also keep in mind that if your old drive has windows on it, and you format that drive, you will need to reinstall windows.

Comment: Is a good question. Maybe you should try to write it differently and not only from your experience. Otherwise, it seems you just don't want to open the computer and check it. Probably C: is the old one, if you only have 2 hard drives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Open it
3. Write down the make & model of each drive & next to it write "old" or "new".
   (Hope they're not both the same)*
4. Look in Disk Management, right click each disk & select Properties
5. Check which letter is allocated to each disk.

Note that C: is likely to be the one you are currently booted from & is unlikely to let you erase it until you can boot from something else.

[image]

*If they are both the same, remove the new one [presumably identifiable by the amount of dust] & test again.

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows system, you can [obtain details for disk drives using diskpart](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/commands/diskpart.php). You can run the utility by [opening a command prompt window](http://support.moonpoint.com/os/windows/win10/cmdprompt/) and typing `diskpart`; you will need to provide credentials for an account with administrator access on the system to run the utility. When the program runs,
you will get a `DISKPART>` prompt. You can select the disk to examine with `select disk disknum` where *disknum* is a number identifying a particular disk. Assuming you have two drives on the system, the numbers would be 0 and 1, since the numbering starts with 0. So you could issue the command `select disk 0` to select the first disk drive. Then type `detail disk` to see the details for the disk, including the drive model number, which will be on the first line of output from the `detail disk` command and a list of all the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) on the drive with the drive letters Windows has assigned and the labels for the partitions. Then issue the command `select disk 1` followed by `detail disk`. If you have additional drives, increase the number used in the `select` command. Example:

```
DISKPART> select disk 0

Disk 0 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

ST2000DL001-9VT156 ATA Device
Disk ID: 819AC4AB
Type   : ATA
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(SATA)#ACPI(PRID)#ATA(C00T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : Yes
Pagefile Disk  : Yes
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : Yes
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 1                      NTFS   Partition    101 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 2     C                NTFS   Partition    201 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 3     D   Data         NTFS   Partition   1660 GB  Healthy
  Volume 4                      NTFS   Partition    450 MB  Healthy    Hidden

DISKPART>
```

As Pablo Gomez said, C is probably a partition on the old drive, which you can hopefully identify from the drive model numbers, but you can verify that.